# EOF error while using grep for today's date

Tags: bash, grep

I have a file, file.log, in the following format:

```
27/07 01:15:10,072  [INFO ] test    Start Batch Calculation Com 
27/07 06:22:27,862  [INFO ] test    End Batch Calculation Com 
27/07 06:22:36,192  [INFO ] test    Start Batch Fact 
27/07 06:22:36,896  [INFO ] test    End Batch Fact 
27/07 06:22:43,607  [INFO ] test    Start Batch Edition
27/07 06:22:44,888  [INFO ] test    End Batch Edition
23/05 01:15:10,072  [INFO ] test    Start Batch Calculation Com 
23/05 06:22:27,862  [INFO ] test    End Batch Calculation Com 
23/05 06:22:36,192  [INFO ] test    Start Batch Fact 
23/05 06:22:36,896  [INFO ] test    End Batch Fact 
23/05 06:22:43,607  [INFO ] test    Start Batch Edition
23/05 06:22:44,888  [INFO ] test    End Batch Edition
```

I am writing a ksh script to get the line which contains the string End Batch Calculation Com of the 23/05.  23/05 is the actual date.
Below is my code:

```
   DateCom=`grep 'End Batch Calculation Com ' file.log |grep "^`date +'%d/%m'`"`
   echo "$DateCom"
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
    ./test.sh: command substitution: line 35: unexpected EOF while looking                         for matching `"'
./test.sh: command substitution: line 36: syntax error: unexpected end                         of file
./test.sh: command substitution: line 35: unexpected EOF while looking                         for matching `"'
./test.sh: command substitution: line 36: syntax error: unexpected end                         of file
date +%d/%m
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
DateCom=$(grep  "^$(date +%d/%m).*End Batch Edition"  Input_file)
echo $DateCom
```

Output will be as follows then:

```
23/05 06:22:44,888 [INFO ] test End Batch Edition
```

I am using $() after variable name to get the command's value into the variable. Checking the system's current date(if it comes starting of a line) with the string Batch Edition. Then printing the value of variable.

**EDIT:**

**1st:**

```
grep "End Batch Edition"  Input_file | grep -o "^$(date +%d/%m)"
```

**2nd:**

```
grep "^$(date +%d/%m).*End Batch Edition"  Input_file | cut -c1-5
```

So above could help you here, 1st solution after EDIT, I am searching for the line which has string mentioned by you then searching today's date and it will print that only.

Solution after OR, will simply search the string which starts from today's date ad have the string, then I am using cut to get the first 5 letters which is nothing but the date and month.

Comment: Sorry I actually wanted to have the date only, that is only the 23/05. Not the whole line. I forget to specify this in the question. Any idea how to do this using grep?

Comment: @tabby: I edited my solution above now, let me know if this helps you, we could write it in awk, sed too though.

Answer (score 0):

Use the dollar-parenthesis notation for command substitution, that allows for nesting:

```
DateCom=$(grep 'End Batch Calculation Com ' file.log |grep "^$(date +'%d/%m')")
```

Comment: @user00001 : Sorry I actually wanted to have the date only, that is only the 23/05. Not the whole line.  I forget to specify this in the question.